# Editable Range Slider

Tags: jquery, salesforce, sliders

I want to change the value of Slider on the basis of Value which I entered.(editable Sliders)

```
    <!--- HTML Code--------->

<div class="form-group" id="AmountdivId">
  <label class="control-label">Advance amount</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
    <input type="text" id="AmountID" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

    //javascript code
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      // Basic Slider: Success
      jQuery('#slider-success').slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20000,
        value: 15000,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#amount").val(ui.value);
          $("#FundingAmtClass").val(ui.value);
          $('#AmountID').val(ui.value);
        },

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an action to input handler

```
$('#AmountID').change(function() {
    var newvalue = $(this).val();
    $('#slider-success').slider( 'value', newvalue );       
    $(this).val( newvalue );
});
```